# Drag an image only horizontally or vertically in android?

Tags: android, android-imageview, drag

I want to control the dragging way of the image in android. It should be moved only in one direction. How can i control it?

Comment: did you try something? If yes please share with us.

Comment: The code i tried moves image in all the direction i couldn't restrict the direction. I searched on the net and couldn't find any examples in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, put a `ScrollView` inside a `HorizontalScrollView`, and the `ImageView` inside the innermost ScrollView.

Hierarchy will look like this:

```
  LinearLayout (ROOT)
  |
  +-- ScrollView (V)
       |
       +-- LinearLayout (1)
            |
            +-- HorizontalScrollView (H)
                |
                +-- LinearLayout (2)
                    |
                    +-- ImageView
```

And let me explain:

`(V)` scrolls in vertical direction only.

`(H)` scrolls in horizontal direction only.

`(1)` and `(2)` are linear layouts used immediately following any ScrollViews. Because, a ScrollView can host only one direct child.

**Note on naming: There's only "ScrollView", and *not*  "VerticalScrollView"**

*What happens when you drag the `ImageView` ?*

Based on the very first direction of the gesture you make, if it's horizontal, the `HorizontalScrollView` will process the action, and the `ScrollView` will sit idle. And if the action was vertical, the `ScrollView` will process the action, and `HorizontalScrollView` will sit idle.