# Android make drag only up and down

Tags: android

Doing Android drag and drop, v is a "TextView" and it's as wide as screen width.

Is it possible to make the "shadowBuilder" below only drag "up and down" and not drag "left and right" ? Because I want it("shadowBuilder" or the TextView v) still fill the whole screen width during the drag process.

Thanks...

```
TextView textDrag;
...

DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v); 
v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, v, 0); 



// here is it 
textDrag = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDrag);
        LayoutParams p = textDrag.getLayoutParams();
        p.width = displaymetrics.widthPixels * 3;
        textDrag.setLayoutParams(p);
        textDrag.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { 
                    //
                    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v); 
                    v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
                    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
                    return true; 

                } else { 
                    return false; 
                } 
            }
        });
```

Comment: In my conceptual, you should fix horizontal drag event value. Can you share your solution to me when you solve it?

Comment: Hi, I did not solve it. I make it 3 times wide of the screen width to escape the problem. (Thus, no matter how you drag it, it still fill the whole screen width)

Comment: Can you show to us your dragshadowbuilder source code a little bit?

Comment: to lv0gun9, I paste the code when onTouch on the textView. Did not override "dragshadowbuilder"

Comment: Check this.

I think it is the answer to you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266785/drag-an-image-only-horizontally-or-vertically-in-android

Comment: Thanks, in my case I can not use ScrollView, but it helps.

Comment: If you solve it. please share to us. :3