# How to realize a Swipe to submit on Android?

Tags: android, animation, drag

I would like to make an animation for submit like that on Android:

[image: Swipe transfer]

**Would anyone an idea how to achieve that?**

> The idea is to drag (horizontal) a View in a ViewGroup (LinearLayout)
>   and be able to recover the position.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16267268/1832221 with just one HorizontalScrollView. But the drag isn't just on arrow.

Comment: Take a look: https://android-arsenal.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use custom `seekbar`

set your own background and icon.

on Complete swipe of `seekbar`, `seekbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` and `circle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

```
  <SeekBar  
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  

    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
```

Use

```
android:thumb="@drawable/drag_thumb"
```

to replace `@drawable/drag_thumb` with your drawable of thumb

```
 android:progressDrawable="@layout/custom_seekbar_layout"
```

to create your own background

```
 android:max="YOUR_TOTAL_PROGRESS"  <--replace YOUR_TOTAL_PROGRESS with your int -->
```

Make your class `implements OnSeekBarChangeListener`

and

```
 seekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);  
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

Now manage events

```
@Override  
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,  
        boolean fromUser) {  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar progress: "+progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
   if(progress == YOUR_TOTAL_PROGRESS)
   {
        seekbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
        circle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
}  
@Override  
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
}  
@Override  
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"seekbar touch stopped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    if (seekBar.getProgress() < YOUR_TOTAL_PROGRESS) {
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
    }
}
```

on complete slide of `seekbar` you can apply transition from bottom to top for the layout which contains the additional info (that shows "Transfer Successful and contains button at bottom").

**slide_in_top.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:toYDelta="0%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

**slide_out_top.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:toYDelta="100%p"
android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :). I just edit to return the picker when the value is not YOUR_TOTAL_PROGRESS. It lacks the design and it's good.

Comment: @lopez.mikhael Good Luck

Comment: Are you sure about " android:progressDrawable="@layout/" I think it's a drawable, not a layout

Comment: @lopez.mikhael as per my knowledge it is drawable only. you can creates layers in drawable.  Use can use Relative layout of `TextView` with text "Slide to..." with `seekbar`

Comment: @lopez.mikhael Can you share the drawables and code if possible? I am trying to achieve something similar but not able to do it?